# Applying a transition in between two states with Javascript behaving erratically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, jquery-events

I'm struggling to understand why the transitions don't behave as expected. It's supposed to apply the "from", then add the "transition" to the "el", then it's supposed to run "to" and finally onTransitionEnd it's supposed to run "callback" (prepended to which is a bit of code which clears the transition properties).

In Webkit browsers, it transitions slideDown correctly, but slideUp is instant. Reverse is true in Firefox.

Erg?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/enhTd/

```
var $ = function(query) {
                var a = [],
                    n = document.querySelectorAll(query),
                    l = n.length;

                for( var i = 0; i<l; i++){
                    a.push(n[i]);
                    }
                if(l>1) {return a;} else {return a[0];}

                },
    $id = function(query) { return document.getElementById(query);},
    getSupportedPropertyName = function(properties) {
        for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
            if (typeof document.body.style[properties[i]] != "undefined") {
                return properties[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    },
    vendorTransitions = ["transition", "msTransition", "webkitTransition", "MozTransition", "OTransition"],
    prefixedTransitionProperty = getSupportedPropertyName(vendorTransitions),
    transition = function(opts){

        opts.from && opts.from();

        if(prefixedTransitionProperty){
            var c = opts.callback || function() {},
                el = opts.el,
                cb = function(event){
                    var ev = event, callback = c;
                    ev.target.removeEventListener(prefixedTransitionProperty+"End", cb);
                    ev.target.style[prefixedTransitionProperty] = "none";
                    if(callback) {
                        callback(ev);
                        }
                    };

            el.style[prefixedTransitionProperty] = opts.transition || "";
            el.addEventListener(prefixedTransitionProperty+"End", cb);
        }

        opts.to && opts.to();

    },
    slideDown = function(el, t){
        var style = el.style,
            h, oh = el.offsetHeight,
            t = t || 1000;

        //Grab real height
        style.height = "";
        h = el.offsetHeight;

        transition({
            "el": el,
            transition: "height "+t+"ms ease",
            from: function() {
                style.height = oh+"px";
            },
            to: function(){
                style.overflow = "hidden";
                style.height = h+"px";
                },
            callback: function(event){
                event.target.style.height = "";
                }
            });


    },
    slideUp = function(el, t){
        var style = el.style,
            h = el.offsetHeight,
            t = t || 1000;

        transition({
            "el": el,
            transition: "height "+t+"ms ease",
            from: function() {
                style.height = h+"px";
                },
            to: function(){
                style.overflow = "hidden";
                style.height = "0";
                }
            });

    },
    slideToggle = function(el, t){
        var t = t || 1000;

        if(el.style.height=="0px"){
            slideDown(el, t);
        } else {
            slideUp(el, t);
        }
    };


slideUp($id("intro"));
$("a[href='#intro']").forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener("click", function(ev) { 
        ev.preventDefault();
        if(ev.target.classList.contains("hide")){
            slideUp($(ev.target.hash));
        } else {
            slideDown($(ev.target.hash));
        }
    });
});
$("li h3").forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener("click", function(ev) { 
        ev.preventDefault();
        slideToggle(ev.target.parentNode);
    });
});
```

Comment: hey man took me like 2 hours to answer your question :p please lemme know if my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15308645/766570) worked for you or not..

Comment: Thanks. Still one bug... I'll try figure out why that's happening...When I try to click on the h3's in the li's then it's still iffy and breaks sometimes (instant on and off)

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers, you cannot just set the initial state, set the final state and expect a CSS transition to work.

Instead, the initial state must be set and then it must be rendered before you can set the final state and expect the transition to run.  The simplest way to cause it to be rendered is to return back to the event loop and then do any further processing (like setting the final state) after a `setTimeout()` call.

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/enhTd/1/ (tested in chrome and ff)

**first:** do what jfriend00 [talked about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15307565/766570):

in your transition function:

```
transition = function (opts) {
    ..
    setTimeout(function() {
        opts.to && opts.to();
    }, 1)
}
```

**second:** the callback wasn't necessary in your `slideDown()` method:

```
slideDown = function (el, t) {
    ..
    take this out:
      /*callback: function (event) {
            event.target.style.height = "";
        }*/
    });
```

from a design point of view.. the callback function wasn't adding any value.. you should just continue from where you left off when it comes to transitions.

**third:** disable slide down when the slide is already down.. but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: The callback is there because if I were to resize the window with the height set, the layout would screw up. (text would be cut off from the bottom of intro, or there'd be a giant gap between intro and the rest, as it remembers the height.)

The timeout was something I tried but didn't work for me (I had 50ms) but now it does...THANKS...

Finally, When I try to click on the h3's in the li's then it's still iffy and breaks sometimes... Ideas?

Comment: well at this point (and after investing all that time trying to resolve our issue.. only to find it introduces another one).. may I ask why are you trying to reinvent the wheel here? You are running across some tricky cross-browser problems, dealing with event loops, timers, dynamic vendor specific css transitions etc to create a transition effect that has millions of ready, tested, and cross-browser implementations online? jQuery UI or bootstrap etc solve this problem more than elegantly. If I where you, I'd use one of those. The best way to win a battle is by not having to fight one.